# How to save AVPlayer last play position

Tags: xcode, avplayer

I want to save the last position of a video i played in an `AVPlayer`. So when i close the app and i want to watch the video later again, it should not start again from the beginning. Is there any possibility that the app remembers the position?

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE**

I'm developing for iOS 6.1.3

Comment: Are you asking for NSUserDefaults or something else? It seems your question is more "how do I save a preference" in general, nothing specific of AVPlayer.

Comment: Yes, i just want to save the `CMTime` object i relation with a specific `AVPlayerItem`. That after restarting the app after a while, i can set the saved `CMTime` to the `AVPlayerItem`. The sense is that i can resume the video at the position i stopped it the last time i watched it. And it should not start always from the beginning. Maybe this describes my problem better.

Comment: Anyone a hint how to do this? Thank you :)

Comment: Look @weichsel answer to wrap a CMTime in an object and then use the pointer in his answer to NSCoding or search NSUserDefaults in the docs, in google, in SO...it's well covered everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AVPlayer's` `currentTime` property.  It returns the playback time of the current `AVPlayerItem`.

To restore the playback time in the next session, you can pass the stored time to `AVPlayer's` `seekToTime:`

```
[self.player seekToTime:storedPlaybackTime];
```

[AVPlayer currentTime docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009530-CH1-SW2)
[AVPlayer seekToTime docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/seekToTime%3a)

**Update**
To persist the `CMTime` returned by currentTime, you can use the [AVFoundation convenience methods provided by NSValue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/NSValue_AVFoundation_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

To wrap `CMTime` in an `NSValue`, use `valueWithCMTime:`

```
[NSValue valueWithCMTime:player.currentTime];
```

To get an CMTime struct from the persisted value, use:

```
CMTime persistedTime = [storeValue CMTimeValue];
```

After you wrapped the `CMTime` struct in a `NSValue` instance, you can use keyed archiver & `NSData` to write the time to disk.

NSHipster has a good article about that topic:http://nshipster.com/nscoding/

Comment: I know how to get the `currentTime` and also how to seek to a specific Time. But how do i save the `currentTime` property. Because i think if i kill the application, all the information, like this `CMTime` object, in which i save the `currentTime`, will get lost.

Comment: I updated my answer. What platform are you developing for. Because e.g. on the Mac it could be, that the Window Restoration protocol (+10.7) might be a good point to store/restore your playback position.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to tell that i am developing for iOS 6.1.3. I also updated my question.

Comment: have you got the solution? @kchromik

Comment: There are several ways to persist the information. You can use CoreData, UserDefaults or something else. Then, you can load the position and set it when you start the playback to its current time.